# Is it possible to use WCF to communicate with Windows kernel mode software?

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, driver, kernel-mode

WCF supports some interoperability bindings. Does any of these bindings allow to communicate with kernel mode sw?

AFAIK kernel mode sw can open named pipes, in the `Local System` security context. Are those named pipes interoperable with WCF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use the Named Pipes Binding in WCF to communicate with the Kernel Mode Software.

While it may be possible, it definitely won't be easy. Creating the WCF Service to serve the data over named pipes and a consumer won't be difficult.

Message Framing in WCF is where you are going to hit your snag. Your client will have to properly frame everything so that WCF can understand what you're trying to call. Here's a link detailing everything if you really want to give it a shot (I link to the last entry so you have links to the rest of the series as well).:

[Message Framing, Part 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2009/02/06/message-framing-part-7.aspx)

Comment: are you sure that named pipes binding in wcf can communicate with non-wcf app?

Comment: @Andrey - From what I've seen, yes. You just have to make sure whatever you're using to communicate over the Named Pipe binding serializes data in the same format (which may be difficult but not impossible).

Comment: in my case I don't worry about serialization yet, my objective here is just to call parameterless argumentless method

Comment: the first snag I hit was making the addresses collide. I explained it further here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789807/how-to-make-a-wcf-named-pipe-address-equal-to-a-winapi-one